# Can I use variables in import statements and function calling in Python?

Tags: python, neural-network

I am creating code for training neural network models and am looking to make it generic so that I can just change the model name and run the code for each model. Can I use variables in import statements and function calling in Python?

```
from transformers import BertModel, BertTokenizer, BertConfig

config=BertConfig.from_pretrained(arch)
```

In these line, I would want to have a variable name rather than Bert that I can change (Bert <--> CTRL <--> any other model)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can

```
from transformers import BertConfig as btcfg
config=btcfg.from_pretrained(arch)
```